# Можно ли в одном процессе принимать подключения, а в другом получать/отправлять сообщения

Tags: c++, linux, c

Есть сервер, в котором главный процесс порождает 2 других процесса Worker. И получается, что в главном процессе у меня реализовано принятие подключений через системный вызов accept(). Дальше дескриптор я отдаю на один из воркеров в другой прооцесс. У меня по этому дескриптору не получилось принять сообщение из воркера.

Есть ли возможность в линуксе в одном процессе принимать соединения, передавать дескриптор в другой процесс и принимать сообщения оттуда?

Comment: Можно. См. ancillary data в [man sendmsg/recvmsg](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg) и также [Unix domain sockets ancillary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624877/7286264) (тут есть [пример](https://www.oocities.org/margineantm/syspp/background/ancillary.html))

Comment: @avp, да спасибо, все заработало